# Выдает ошибки:<: недопустимо, правый оператор имеет тип "int (__thiscall StudenR::* )(std::ifstream &)";

Tags: c++

```
#include "targetver.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class StudenR
{
    string Name;
    int NumGroup; 
    string Sex;
    int Marks[5];
public:
    StudenR();
    StudenR(ifstream &fin);
    bool Read(ifstream &fin);
    void Write(ofstream &fout);
    int AvMark(ifstream &fin);
    void SetMarks(int &marks);
    int GetMarks(int i) { return Marks[i]; }
    ~StudenR();
};

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "StudenR.h"
using namespace std;

StudenR::StudenR()
{
    Name = "<unknown>";
    NumGroup = 0;
    Sex = 'x';
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        Marks[i] = 0;
}
StudenR::StudenR(ifstream &fin) {
    fin >> Name;
    fin >> NumGroup;
    fin >> Sex;
    for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
    fin >> Marks[i];
    }
}
bool StudenR::Read(ifstream &fin) {
    if (!(fin >> Name))return false;
    if (!(fin >> NumGroup))return false;
    if (!(fin >> Sex))
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        if (!(fin >> Marks[i]))return false;
    return true;
}
int StudenR::AvMark(ifstream &fin) {
    int AvMark = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        fin >> Marks[i];
        AvMark += Marks[i];

    }
    AvMark /= 5;
    return AvMark;

}
void StudenR::SetMarks(int &marks) {
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
        this->Marks[i] = marks;
}

void StudenR::Write(ofstream &fout) {
    fout << Name << " " << NumGroup << " " << Sex << " ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        fout << Marks[i] << " ";
    }
    fout << endl;
}
StudenR::~StudenR()
{
}


#include "stdafx.h"
#include "StudenR.h"
using namespace std;

void Read1(StudenR*students, ifstream &fin, int &n);
void Write(StudenR*students, ofstream &fout, int n);
void WriteAvM(ofstream&fout, StudenR*students, int n, ifstream&fin);
void Sort(StudenR*&studets, int n);
int main()
{
    ifstream fin("Text.txt");
    ofstream fout("res.txt");

    StudenR *students = new StudenR[100];

    int n = 0;
    Read1(students, fin, n);
    Write(students, fout, n);
    fout << endl << endl << endl;

    WriteAvM(fout, students, n, fin);
    fout << endl << endl << endl;
    Sort( students, n);
    Write(students, fout, n);

    fin.close();
    fout.close();

    delete[]students;
    return 0;
}

void Read1(StudenR *students, ifstream &fin, int &n) {
    n = 0;
    for (; !fin.eof(); n++) {
        if (!students[n].Read(fin))return;
    }
}
void Write(StudenR *students, ofstream &fout, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        students[i].Write(fout);
}


void WriteAvM(ofstream &fout, StudenR *students, int n, ifstream&fin) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        students[i].Write(fout);
        int AvMark = students[i].AvMark(fin);
        fout << "AvMark" << i + 1 << "=" << AvMark << endl;
    }
}
void Sort( StudenR*&students, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - 1-i; j++) {
        if (students[j].AvMark<students[j + 1].AvMark){//здесь выдает ошибку


                StudenR s = students[j];
                students[j] = students[j + 1];
                students[j + 1] = s;

        }
    }

        }
    }
```

/* <: недопустимо, правый оператор имеет тип "int (__thiscall StudenR::* )(std::ifstream &)"; <: недопустимо, левый операнд имеет тип "int (__thiscall StudenR::* )(std::ifstream &)"; "StudenR::AvMark": нестандартный синтаксис; используйте "&", чтобы создать указатель на член */

Answer (score 0):

`AvMark` - это функция, её нужно вызвать с аргументом типа `std::ifstream`. Кстати, `std::ifstream` является наследником `std::istream`, логичнее работать через его интерфейс, т.к. при этом можно использовать любые потоки ввода, а не только файлы.

Comment: в данном  коде  AvMark  указатель на функцию_член класса  Student,

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, функция `AvMark` - это часть класса, а не объекта. Указатель на функцию - это `&StudenR::AvMark`, тут же происходит обращение к конкретному объекту.

Comment: вы говорите о том, как в коде нужно инициализировать указатель на функцию_член, а компилятор  просто ищет в классе то, что вызываем в коде для обьекта, Компилятор находит в  классе     такое имя и видит, что это указатель на функцию член. А вот  students[j].AvMark(...)  это  int  получившийся  в результате вызова функции. Вообшем об этом долго говорить, поскольку на это можно смотреть с разного уровня абстракции

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, то, что вы говорите - это в лучшем случае внутреннее представление компилятора, в худшем - вообще не соответствует истине. gcc, например, прямо говорит, что `reference to non-static member function must be called`, не предполагая, что кто-то попытается получить адрес функции через объект (хотя и использует слово reference).

Answer (score 0):

Чисто формально - вам нужно сравнивать не указатели на функции, а средние значения, т.е. вроде бы просто написать не

```
if (students[j].AvMark<students[j + 1].AvMark)
```

а

```
if (students[j].AvMark(fin)<students[j + 1].AvMark(fin))
```

где `fin` - этот ваш входной файл.

Но это ничего не решит. Потому что ваша функция берет на себя слишком много - она и читает данные, и вычисляет среднее. Так что при каждом сравнении (а их может быть много) она будет опять лезть в файл и пытаться читать данные, чтобы вычислить среднее. Понимаете, много-много раз лезть в давно прочитанный файл и пытаться читать его?

В данном конкретном случае вам нужно добавить поле средней оценки в класс, при чтении вычислять его и сохранять, а потом сравнивать это поле.

А на будущее запомнить - хороший дизайн - когда функция занимается логически **одним** делом, а не пытается объять необъятное...